# how to let Jpackage installor to copy resource folder to the install dir?

Tags: javafx, jpackage

I can use jpackage to convert a excutable jar to a installor exe.

but my program dependents on a resource folder which users can use it, after installation, I have to copy resource folder to the installation folder.

how can I let Jpackage installor to  copy resource folder to the install dir ?

I have tried --app-content  --install-dir  --resource-dir , but it doesnt work~

Comment: What is the purpose of this "resource folder"? Is it supposed to be writable by the application? If so, then having it located in the installation directory is likely a mistake. What if the user installs the application in a location that requires admin/root privileges? Typically, an application will use a "known location" to store files usable by both the application itself and the user, such as an application-specific directory under the user home directory, or a platform-specific location such as `%LOCALAPPDATA%` on Windows.