Jpackage "resource-dir" command not working
I have a NetBeans project that I'm trying to deploy using an installer, everything's good until i installed the app until i realized that the app couldn't find a Jaspersoft archive that needs to be a in a folder inside the archive programs folder. Looking for a way to add the folder i found the --resource-dir commands, so i put the path folder inside the command. But when i deploy the package i cannot find my folder, the installer makes the folder inside Programs archive folder but inside of it theres nothing related to that folder. I really need that folder to be there, so if any ideas of whats happening?
Here it's the command that i used for the jpackage deploy.
]jpackage -i dist --main-jar LABELMASTER.jar --icon D:\Marquitos\Documentos\NetBeansProjects\LABELMASTER\dist\LM.ico --type exe --resource-dir D:\Marquitos\Documentos\NetBeansProjects\LABELMASTER\src --vendor SII-inc. --win-shortcut --name LabelMaster

I need that src folder to be inside the installer
And this is the folder what's the installer creates, but it doesn't have the resource dir that i added
Someone knows if its any other command that could help me with it or im doing something wrong, im sorry for my bad English but i couldn't find anything related to this in Spanish community. Thanks by the way.

Note that --resource-dir is not for including application resources in the application. That option is for overriding jpackage resources used to build the application package. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html

Can you clarify what you mean by "jaspersoft archive" and how it is used by your application?

The app uses jaspersoft templates, that can be filled by data select in the app, basically its a labels app but i need those templates because the code gets them from that  relative path.

If the template is a resource, then it should be embedded in the jar file with your application's class files. This is created before you create the app package via jpackage. At run-time, you would load the template with Class::getResource or Class::getResourceAsStream.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77873737/how-to-let-jpackage-installor-to-copy-resource-folder-to-the-install-dir/78370817#78370817

@jean-françois-fabre Any reason why my answer got deleted?

i did nt do it :p
